# Load view from helper Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can i load view from helper in codeigniter? I have been looking for a present, but it seems no one has discussed it.

Comment: This isn't documented in the helper section of the documentation, but in the ["Creating Libraries" section (Utilizing CodeIgniter Resources within Your Library)](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html). It's a bit confusing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can. Create your helper, say `views_helper.php`:

```
if(!function_exists('view_loader')){

  function view_loader($view, $vars=array(), $output = false){
    $CI = &get_instance();
    return $CI->load->view($view, $vars, $output);
  }
}
```

`$view` is the view file name (as you would normally use), and `$vars` an array of variables you want to pass (as you would normally do), pass a `true` as optional third parameter to have it returned (as it would normally happen) as content instead of it just being loaded;

Just load your helper (or autoload it):

```
$this->load->helper('views');
$data = array('test' => 'test');
view_loader('myview', $data)
```

Comment: nice! But maybe you can add the third parameter for direct output?

Comment: @ThomasDavidPlat Thanks, updated answer to reflect your suggestion

Comment: I found this while searching `$page = $this->load->view('view', $data, TRUE);` , what can be passed as parameters as above (representing the file name, variable, optional parameters in view)?

Comment: The same. It's the same way of doing things, really