# Unable to pass vairables through helper function Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

On my Codeigniter Custom helper I would like to be able to pass data through my load_controller function $params

But I cannot pass any data through `load_controller('controller', 'function', $setting);`

**Custom Helper**

```
<?php

if (!function_exists('load_controller'))
{
    function load_controller($controller, $method = 'index', $params = '')
    {
        require_once(APPPATH . 'controllers/' . $controller . '.php');

        $controller = new $controller();

        return $controller->$method();
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to do something like this below

```
<?php

class Column_left extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {
        $data['modules'] = array();

        $setting = array('width' => '100', 'height' => '100');

        $data['modules'][] = load_controller('Slideshow', 'index', $setting);

        return $this->load->view('column_left_view', $data, true);
    }
}
```

And then on the Slideshow controller be able to get width or height

```
<?php

class Slideshow extends CI_Controller {

    public function index($setting) {

        echo $setting['width'];

        return $this->load->view('slideshow_view', null, true);
    }
}
```

**Question** How can I make my helper be able to pass data through the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont you need to pass the data `$setting` to your controller?

Try this:

```
function load_controller($controller, $method = 'index', $params = ''){
        require_once(APPPATH . 'controllers/' . $controller . '.php');
        $controller = new $controller();
        return $controller->$method($params); //<-- here we are passing the $setting info
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @CodeGodie working and thanks to every one else for suggestions and advice

Comment: No problem, anyitime :)

Answer (score 0):

You could return an array from that function.

**For Ex:**

```
function your_helper_function(){
    $variable1 = 10;
    $variable2 = 20;
    $dataArray = array($aVariable, $aVariable2);
    return $dataArray;
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to work it in with my helper function like what codeigniter does with there views

Comment: Check out this link..I think this will help you although I have never tried it   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21086011/load-view-from-helper-codeigniter